# Complexification of forced harmonic oscillator equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

The problem I am working on is:

Find the solution of the given initial-value problem.

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+20y=-3\sin2t$$

$$y(0)=y'(0)=0$$

The part I am having trouble on, is the complexification:

How do I turn $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+20y=-3\sin2t$$ into

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+20y=e^{it}$$

I have tried looking up similar examples on Math SE and Google, but can't find anything that helps, and my textbook just shows how to turn $\sin t$ into $e^{it}$.

Comment: Because it's linear...maybe ...Thats why you can write that But here it should be $e^{-2it}$ since it's $\sin(2t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you have is equivalent to the imaginary part of

$$ y'' + 4y' + 20y = -3e^{2it} $$

If you don't understand why, refer to Euler's formula
$$ e^{ia} = \cos a + i\sin a $$

We can look for a particular solution of the form $y_p = Ae^{2it}$ where $A$ is some complex number. If you don't know why it has this form, refer to the method of undetermined coefficients.

Plugging in gives
$$ -4Ae^{2it} + 8iAe^{2it} + 20Ae^{2it} = -3e^{2it} $$

Dividing through by the exponential we get
\begin{align} (16+8i)A &= -3 \\ A &= -\frac{3}{8(2+i)} = -\frac{3}{40}(2-i) \end{align}

Taking the imaginary part of the solution
$$ y_p(t) = \Im\left\{ -\frac{3}{40}(2-i)e^{2it} \right\} = -\frac{3}{20}\cos(2t) - \frac{3}{40}\sin(2t) $$

---

For the full solution, the characteristic polynomial is
$$ r^2 + 4r + 20 = 0 $$
which has solutions $r = -2 \pm 4i$. Therefore
$$ y(t) = e^{-2t}\big(c_1 \cos (4t) + c_2\sin (2t) \big) -\frac{3}{20}\cos(2t) - \frac{3}{40}\sin(2t) $$

You can find the constants using the given initial conditions.

---

A different way using complex methods is start first the the full complex function
$$ y(t)_{\Bbb C} = C_1 e^{(-2+4i)t} + C_2 e^{(-2-4i)t} - \frac{3}{40}(2-i)e^{2it} $$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are complex, then the derivative is easier to compute
\begin{align} y(0)_{\Bbb C} &= C_1 + C_2 - \frac{3}{40}(2-i) = 0 \\ y'(0)_{\Bbb C} &= (2+4i)C_1 + (-2-4i)C_2 - \frac{3}{20}i(2-i) = 0 \end{align}

Proceed as usual and take the imaginary part at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+20y=e^{it}$$

Should have been $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+20y=-3e^{i2t}$$

Note that you want either the real part or the imaginary part of this complex differential equation to be a solution to your original differential equation.

Comment: How did you go from $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+20y=-3\sin2t$ to $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+20y=-3e^{i2t}$?

Comment: The imaginary part of$ -3e^{i2t}$ is what you like to have, namely $ -3\sin2t$

Comment: How do you go from one to the other though?

Comment: Keep the same coefficient and change sin(at) or cos(at) to $e^{ait}$